# Не грузит файл с простого POST yii2

Tags: php, yii2, файлы, post

Не грузит файл!

По запросу post приходит файл:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryqvKhry9woGWYaIWC
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="bgh.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

Я его принимаю так:

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $model = new UploadForm();

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
            $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance(Yii::$app->request->post(), 'file');
            if ($model->upload()) {
                // file is uploaded successfully
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[**The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0:  Uploading Files.**](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload#wiring-up)

`UploadedFile::getInstance` первый параметр ожидает экземпляр объекта типа `UploadForm`.

```
public function actionUpload()
{
    $model = new UploadForm();

    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost) {
        $model->imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
        if ($model->upload()) {
            // file is uploaded successfully
            return;
        }
    }
}
```